# Undefined checking on variable practice

Tags: javascript, undefined, void

is

```
if( typeof myVar === "undefined" )
```

the same as

```
if( myVar===void(0) )
```

?

And what is the best pratice, if there is one between these ? Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [MDN Docs for `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined#Typeof_operator_and_undefined),

> One reason to use `typeof` is that it does not throw an error if the
>   variable has not been defined.
>
> ```
> // x has not been defined before
> if (typeof x === 'undefined') { // evaluates to true without errors
>    // these statements execute
> }
>
> if(x === undefined){ // throws a ReferenceError
>
> }
> ```
>
> **However, this kind of technique should be avoided.** JavaScript is a statically scoped language, so knowing if a variable is defined can be
>   read by seeing whether it is defined in an enclosing context. The only
>   exception is the global scope, but the global scope is bound to the
>   global object, so checking the existence of a variable in the global
>   context can be done by checking the existence of a property on the
>   global object (using the in operator, for instance).

From the same document's [`void` section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined#Void_operator_and_undefined)

```
var x;
if (x === void 0) {
   // these statements execute
}

// y has not been defined before
if (y === void 0) {
   // throws a ReferenceError (in contrast to `typeof`)
}
```

**Conclusion**

So, when you use `typeof` to check if the variable's value is `undefined`, it will not throw an exception. But direct comparison with `undefined` or comparison with `void 0` will throw an exception.

Comment: You voted to close and then answered?

Comment: @Ian Yes. This piece of information was missing from that question. Perhaps, I should have added this information to the other answer?

Comment: Hmm I guess technically. It's great information (especially if it's missing), it was just weird to me to put it in what will be closed as duplicate (hopefully).